# Bootstrap - why does "control-label" class doesn't affect the label?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with the bootstrap horizontal form alignment at the moment, and faced a problem.
In this example, the `control-label` class should move the  label closer the the email input field, but it doesn't happen.

The question is why?
Thank you in advance!

You can test it at JSfiddle, where you can change the preview window size: https://jsfiddle.net/xm5kwyqo/

---

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-xs-12">

<form class="form-horisontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName">Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text"
    id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input class="form-control" type="email"
    id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">  
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectSite">Site</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="selectSite">
    <option>Choose...</option>
    <option>lynda.com</option>
    <option>raybo.org</option>
    <option>iviewsource.com</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="inputAddList"
      type="checkbox">Add me to e-mail blast
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputComments">Comments</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" 
    id="inputComments"></textarea>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  
  value="submit">
</form>

    </section>
  </div><!-- row -->   
</div><!-- content container -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a miss-spelled issue. Horizontal, **not** horiSontal

Replace :

```
<form class="form-horisontal">
```

By :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xm5kwyqo/1/